# Slidable panel Control for Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, twitter, controls, sliding

I need to create 'slidable panel' control for WP8. Very similar to the one that was used by the old twitter application on ipad (landscape UI).

It's pretty hard to describe in words, here is a link to an article describing how to implement it on ios:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/posts/how-to-build-the-twitter-ipad-user-experience

Sorry, i can't post image to give you a quick overview (stackoverflow reputation...) you will find some in the article above.

As you can see it's basically a stack of 'views' that can overlaps, and you can slide them around.

- Is there any third party control similar to this for Windows Phone
  8.x?
- If not could you provide some guidance on how you would implement it?
- Maybe it's not the good way to do it on WP, in this case what's the WP way to do this?

PS: i am new to WP development,  ios/android background.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not exactly what you are looking for but [this widget](http://slideview.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=slideview) can be a pretty good base for your control.